# How to query the tree?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

I encountered an interesting  problem based on tree-data-structure.

> We are given a tree which has *N* nodes, with *1≤N≤10<sup>5</sup>*.
>
> Time starts from second 1 and it continues for *q* seconds.
>
> At each second, the value of each internal node is transferred to all of its child nodes. This happens with all the nodes, except leaf nodes.
>
> Sometimes, at a given time *p* (seconds), we are asked to return the current value of node *x*.

There is this *O(logN)* approach: just find the *p*<sup>th</sup> ancestor of the given node *x*, and output its value.

## A harder version of the same problem

> Sometimes, at a given time *p* (seconds), we are asked to return the current value of node *x*, **or** we are said to update the value of node *x* to *y*.

How to solve this problem for *q* queries (seconds) efficiently, where *1≤q≤10<sup>5</sup>*.

### Example

#### Input

*N*=5, *q*=8

Edges of the tree:-

```
4 3
3 1
5 2
1 2
```

Values of nodes 1 to 5:-

```
1 10 4 9 4
```

Queries:-

- 1<sup>st</sup> second:- `Add(1,6)`. Add the value 6 to node 1.
- 2<sup>nd</sup> second:- What is the current value of node 3? `(?,3)`
- 3<sup>rd</sup> second:- `Add(3,5)`
- 4<sup>th</sup> second:- `(?,3)`
- 5<sup>th</sup> second:- `Add(2,2)`
- 6<sup>th</sup> second:- `Add(5,10)`
- 7<sup>th</sup> second:- `(?,5)`
- 8<sup>th</sup> second:- `(?,4)`

#### Expected Output

- 6
- 0
- 33
- 25

#### Explanation

- 1<sup>st</sup> second: 6,1,1,13,14 (Values of all nodes)
- 2<sup>nd</sup> second: 0,6,6,14,15
- 3<sup>rd</sup> second: 0,0,5,20,21
- 4<sup>th</sup> second: 0,0,0,25,21
- 5<sup>th</sup> second: 0,2,0,25,21
- 6<sup>th</sup> second:  0,0,0,25,33
- 7<sup>th</sup> second: 0,0,0,25,33
- 8<sup>th</sup> second: 0,0,0,25,33

How to answer the queries efficiently?

Comment: The running time of your original algorithm depends on the height of the tree, which need not be $\log N$.

Comment: You can compute the kth ancestor of a tree in logN time using this trick:-https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kth-ancestor/problem

Comment: You can compute the $k$-th ancestor of a vertex in a tree of $n$ vertices in constant time after a linear-time preprocessing by using $O(n)$ extra space. Notice that you need time and space $\Omega(n)$ anyway. See [level ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_ancestor_problem).

Comment: This question is from an ongoing competition https://www.codechef.com/OCT19A/problems/BACREP